# How to round BigDecimal smaller than 1

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I want to round decimal number to nearest Natural Number.
Example:

```
public static void main(String[] arguments){
    BigDecimal a=new BigDecimal("2.5");
    BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal("0.5");
    System.out.println(a.round(new MathContext(1,RoundingMode.UP)));
    System.out.println(b.round(new MathContext(1,RoundingMode.UP)));       
    }
```

Expected output

```
3
1
```

Real output

```
3
0.5
```

The problem is that number 0.5 is rounded to 0.5 instead of 1
How to Round BigDecimal smaller than 1

Comment: is this a bug or something , still wondering  intvalue =  intvalue.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP); works well

Comment: Yes,setScale(0) works, but I have no idea why is BigDecimal round method working so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like :

```
 BigDecimal intvalue= new BigDecimal("0.5");
 intvalue =  intvalue.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: @JishnuPrathap Only if you want `0.3` to also be rounded to `1`. `HALF_UP` is usually safer.

Comment: @Pshemo OP has used RoundingMode.UP in his question , and HALF_UP and UP are used for different purposes.they are just different not saffer or somethin

Comment: @JishnuPrathap You are right, my bad. I saw in example `0.5` and though that OP meant half-rounding. Again, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you want...

```
BigDecimal a=new BigDecimal("2.5");
BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal("0.5");
System.out.println(Math.round(a.doubleValue()));
System.out.println(Math.round(b.doubleValue()));
```

This will give you output as `3 and 1` ...

Comment: This will also give him 3 for an input of 2.1

Comment: @ZaidMalhis Thank you... Updated my answer for that

Comment: but double cannot store exactly most BigDecimal values

Answer (score 1):

```
BigDecimal b=new BigDecimal("0.5");
b = b.setScale(0,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
System.out.println(b.round(MathContext.DECIMAL32));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to round BigDecimal smaller than 1.

```
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("2.5");
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.5");

    System.out.println(a.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP));
    System.out.println(b.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(Math.round(b.doubleValue()));
```

Comment: Are you asking or telling?